# Are Stripe API Calls Vulnerable To Attacks If User-Supplied Data Is Passed to Retrieve Objects By ID

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am programming a Stripe integration in PHP. At several points in my integration, it would be convenient to provide user-supplied data and pass it to a call to the Stripe API to retrieve an object.

An example would be:

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
$stripe->checkout->sessions->retrieve($id);
```

and there are also similar calls in other scripts referring to other objects.

I don't know what is going on behind the scenes when I make this sort of call. Can I trust Stripe's API to be safe against attacks like this, or is it better to design my application in such a way to avoid making such calls using user-supplied data?

Comment: `Can I trust Stripe's API`...if you can't, then they would have a serious credibility problem. But we can't answer that. Ask to see the results of their penetration testing (which hopefully they carry out regularly), if you're worried. Ask if they test themselves for SQL injection problems and so on - I guess that's what you're thinking of as the threat? Or is it something else? Anyway it's hard to see how you're going to avoid passing user-supplied data, if that's what you need. What would you do instead - get your application to invent the IDs??

Comment: @ADyson One alternative would be to only ever call the Stripe API in response to webhooks, and in this script, have additional security such as checking that it originates from one of Stripe's IP's. Then, I would have greater trust in the provided ID, I could store the relevant info in a local database, and I could look any user-provided ID's up in my local database, so no user-supplied data would ever end up in the API.

An alternative would be to check the formatting of the provided ID and only allow certain characters.

Answer (score 1):

The Stripe API will respond with an error if invalid data is provided.  You would need to make sure you're handling those potential errors correctly on your end.

The primary danger in the scenario you're describing is when someone passes in legitimate data that belongs to someone else.  If someone gets ahold of another person's Checkout Session ID somehow, for example, you may end up thinking that person is not who they claim to be.  This kind of thing should be handled as part of the user authentication process on your end before using the data they provide, showing them any sensitive information, or performing any sensitive operations.

Generally speaking you should always validate/sanitize user input as a best practice before using it do anything, be it a local operation, calling a third-party API, etc.